# Determining the dimension of the Lagrangian Grassmannian through action of symplectic group

Tags: manifolds, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds, symplectic-geometry, grassmannian

After reading chapter 9 in Lee's book on smooth manifolds, I'm trying to figure out the dimension of the Lagrangian Grassmannian in $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$, and I'm wondering if anyone can help me out.

I know that the group $Sp(2n, \mathbb R)$ acts transitively on the LG, which means that I can give it a smooth manifold structure who's dimension is equal to the codimension in $Sp(2n,\mathbb R)$ of the isotropy subgroup of an arbitrary point (so a Lagrangian plane) in the LG. But I'm not sure on how to find this codimension without resulting to some possibly complicated linear algebra.

I already know that the dimension of $Sp(2n,\mathbb R)$ is $n(2n+1)$, and I'm wondering if there's a simple way to find the dimension of this isotropy subgroup. Does anyone have an idea on how to think about this problem more simply? I'm also not completely sure on why it should be a **closed** subgroup, maybe knowing this could help in figuring out the dimension (maybe I can somehow write it as a level set of a smooth map?).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that for $n=1$ $sp(2,\mathbb{R}) = sl(2,\mathbb{R})$. In this case every line in the plane is Lagrangian. The isotropy group of the line $y=0$,  consists precisely of upper triangular matrices with determinant $1$. This group has real dimension $2$, maybe it can be helpful for the general case.

Comment: @NickL Yes, this low dimensional case is pretty simple. But I'm not sure on how to find the more general case (that is, without having to do lots of linear algebra). Do you know of a 'simpler' way to .think about the higher dimensional case without having to work through too much algebra?

Comment: Not really, sorry. It is not hard to work out what is the isotropy group of a half dimensional hyperplane in $Gl_{2n}$, for example take $0 = x_{1} = x_{2} = \ldots = x_{n}$ (we may pick symplectic form which makes this Lagrangian). it will just be $2n \times 2n$ matrices with a $n \times n$ block of $0$'s in the lower left corner. Then, I guess you have to work out the condition for such a matric to be symplectic and count parameters... symplectic geometry textbooks might have this.